# Overlapping X labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

So i'm kinda new to matplotlib, and i couldnt find an approriate answer for my problem, so here we go:

I'm trying to plot the boxplot below, but the xlabels are overlapping, how do i change the x label frequency, or expand the size so it can fit all the numbers?

[image]

I tried the following:

```
x_ticks = np.arrange(0, 52, 2)
plt.xticks(x_ticks)
```

But the x label end up not looking very good

[image]

Comment: You could try plt.xticks(rotation=45) or any other angle for that matter